# Converting facebook comment date to unix

Tags: php, facebook

been trying to convert this facebook output:

```
      Thursday, 22 November 2012 at 12:51
```

To unixtimestamp in PHP ... :) tried all sorts of version from this forum, srttime ... never got to real answer.

Thanks for your time!

Mart

Comment: Post the "all sorts of version from this forum" so we can see if you're doing it incorrectly or suggest a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) can handle it just fine:

```
$fbd = 'Thursday, 22 November 2012 at 12:51';
echo strtotime(str_replace($fbd, ' at ', ' ')); // 1353585060
```

Alternatively, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) in conjunction with [`DateTime::getTimestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php):

```
$fbd = 'Thursday, 22 November 2012 at 12:51';
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F Y * H:i', $fbd)->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Thats excactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
$fb = 'Thursday, 22 November 2012 at 12:51';
$stamp = strtotime( str_replace(' at ', ' ', $fb );
echo "${stamp}\n";
echo date("l, d F Y, H:i", $stamp );
```

will produce:

```
1353585060
Thursday, 22 November 2012, 12:51
```